# How to add an ssh key from other computer to my Ubuntu server

Tags: server, ssh, remote, remote-access

how can I add an SSH-key generated from a computer of a friend to my server?

Currently I don't have access to his computer he just sent me his SSH key.

Comment: Easiest method is ssh-copy-id from the duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to append the key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in your server

Comment: ssh-copy-id is easier and more automated =)

Comment: @Panther yes but "Currently I don't have access to his computer he just sent me his SSH key."